# Count the same occurrences from one column and store the incremental count in a new column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

For a given pair of `cat_id, subcat_id`, I want to count the occurrences of the same `brand_id` and store the incremental count in a new column called `counter`:

```
cat_id  subcat_id   product_code customer_id  quantity  brand_id    
----------------------------------------------------------------
  123      456        AB,CD         111          2         1         
  123      456          CD          111          3         1          
  123      456          AB          222          2         1          
  123      789        AB,CD         111          2         2          
  123      789          CD          111          3         2          
  123      789          AB          222          2         2
```

The result should be:

```
cat_id  subcat_id   product_code customer_id  quantity  brand_id   counter 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  123      456        AB,CD         111          2         1          1
  123      456          CD          111          3         1          2
  123      456          AB          222          2         1          3
  123      789        AB,CD         111          2         2          1
  123      789          CD          111          3         2          2
  123      789          AB          222          2         2          3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by cat_id, subcat_id order by customer_id, quantity)
from t;
```